# Android drawing short colors

Tags: android, colors, bitmap, drawing

I am using the RGB565 format for pixels which only requires 16bits to hold each pixel. Unfortunately the Android Bitmap class is integer only as far as I can tell. This means that I have to double the memory I use per pixel. Is there anyway I can draw a color to the canvas directly so I don't have to store my bitmap with integers?

Comment: You may not be saving the memory that you think you are. Hopefully, @RomainGuy and Chet Haase will release the slides from their "Sticky UIs" presentation yesterday at AnDevCon II, where they went into some of the details of this.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. I wrapped my array of RGB565 short pixels in a ShortBuffer, then I was able to create a Bitmap by using copyPixelsFromBuffer(). From the docs, "The data in the buffer is not changed in any way (unlike setPixels(), which converts from unpremultipled 32bit to whatever the bitmap's native format is." This makes me believe that I am actually saving half the memory on the Bitmap.